# Remove Class using JQuery using Contains

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove the class "hasChild" from the following,

```
<li class="theme-nav-item selected enabled hasChild" data-nav-url="http://www.removed.com/page/nav/3353642"></li>
```

by targeting the value 3353642 using the following JQuery but the class is not getting removed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(document).ready( function($j) {
    $j("li.hasChild > a.theme-nav-link").each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace(this.href, '#');
    });
    $j("li.theme-nav-title > a").each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace(this.href, '#');
    });
    $j("li:contains('3353642')").removeClass("hasChild");
});

</script>
```

The href replacements are working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [*attribute contains selector*](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead

```
$j('li[data-nav-url*="3353642"]').removeClass('hasChild')
```

The [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector is for text content.

---

Given your attribute value, you could also make the selector more specific by using the [*attribute ends-with selector*](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
 $j('li[data-nav-url$="/3353642"]')
```

Comment: Worked perfect!